# Grab transfer details in TRONSCAN

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to write a Python code to grab all TRC20 transactions for a specific address. I referred to the tronscan documentation, but the final outcome was "**No TRC20 transfers found for address Txxxxxxxxxxxxxxx**" in any address I put. Please help me solve this problem. Thank you so much.

```
`import requests

def get_trc20_transfers(tron_address, api_key):
    base_url = "https://apilist.tronscan.org/api"
    endpoint = f"/token_trc20/transfers"

    params = {
        "address": tron_address,
        "limit": 20,  # You can adjust the limit as needed
        "start": 0,   # You can adjust the start index as needed
        "api_key": api_key,  # Include your Tronscan API key here
    }

    try:
        response = requests.get(base_url + endpoint, params=params)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            transfers = data.get("data")
            return transfers
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch TRC20 transfers. Status code: {response.status_code}")
            return None
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tron_address = "TXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  # Replace with the TRON address you want to query
    tronscan_api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"  # Replace with your Tronscan API key

    trc20_transfers = get_trc20_transfers(tron_address, tronscan_api_key)

    if trc20_transfers:
        print("TRC20 Transfers:")
        for transfer in trc20_transfers:
            print(transfer)

    else:
        print(f"No TRC20 transfers found for address {tron_address}.")
`
```

I just want to grab all transaction first and connect to mysql for the telegram bot in next step....

Answer (score 1):

You were one step away from victory) Your script stops at this string,  transfers = data.get("data"),  in its place you had to write,  transfers = data["token transfers"], and that's it working well.